# how to configure noise_reduce() function( import noisereduce) for sin wave frequency above 500Hz

Tags: python, audio, signals, signal-processing, noise-reduction

we would like to check as how to configure noise_reduce() python function( import noisereduce) for sin wave of frequency above 500Hz as it reduces the stationary noise/non-stationary noise for the tone less than 500Hz with noised smoothed output however it kills tone above 500hz along with noise though we had changed the default configuration below and it would be great if someone comment on this issue thanks, and also it works with chirps(50 to 10Khz) and looks like to me something to play with below default configuration

reduce_noise(
y,
sr,
stationary=False,
y_noise = None,
prop_decrease = 1.0,
time_constant_s=2.0,
freq_mask_smooth_hz=500,
time_mask_smooth_ms=50,
thresh_n_mult_nonstationary=2,
sigmoid_slope_nonstationary=10,
n_std_thresh_stationary = 1.5,
tmp_folder=None,
chunk_size=600000,
padding=30000,
n_fft=1024,
win_length=None,
hop_length=None,
clip_noise_stationary = True,
use_tqdm=False,
n_jobs = 1
):